# Sentiment analysis using python

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have some text files containing movie reviews I need to find out whether the review is good or bad. I tried the following code but it's not working:

```
import nltk
with open("c:/users/user/desktop/datascience/moviesr/movies-1-32.txt", 'r') as m11:
    mov_rev = m11.read()
mov_review1=nltk.word_tokenize(mov_rev)
bon="crap aweful horrible terrible bad bland trite sucks unpleasant boring dull moronic dreadful disgusting distasteful flawed ordinary slow senseless unoriginal weak wacky uninteresting unpretentious "
bag_of_negative_words=nltk.word_tokenize(bon)
bop="Absorbing Big-Budget Brilliant Brutal Charismatic Charming Clever Comical Dazzling Dramatic Enjoyable Entertaining Excellent Exciting  Expensive Fascinating Fast-Moving First-Rate Funny Highly-Charged Hilarious Imaginative Insightful Inspirational Intriguing Juvenile Lasting Legendary Pleasant Powerful Ripping Riveting Romantic Sad  Satirical Sensitive  Sentimental Surprising Suspenseful Tender Thought Provoking Tragic Uplifting Uproarious"
bop.lower()
bag_of_positive_words=nltk.word_tokenize(bop)
vec=[]
for i in bag_of_negative_words:
    if i in mov_review1:
        vec.append(1)
    else:
        for w in bag_of_positive_words:
            if w in moview_review1:
                vec.append(5)
```

So I am trying to check whether the review contains a positive word or a negative word. If it contains a negative word then a value of 1 will be assigned to the vector vec else a value of 5 will be assigned. But the output I am getting is an empty vector.

Please help. Also, please suggest others way of solving this problem.

Comment: What debugging have you done? This sounds like a pure code review question, and there are other SE sites for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to search from the databases of official "bad words" that google publishes in this link [Google's official list of bad words](http://fffff.at/googles-official-list-of-bad-words/).
Also, here is the link for the good words [Not the official list of good words](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/wordlist/positivewords.shtml)

For the code, I would do it like this:

```
textArray = file('dir_to_your_text','r').read().split()

#Bad words should be listed like this for the split function to work
# "*** ****** **** ****" the stars are for the cenzuration :P
badArray = file('dir_to_your_bad_word_file).read().split()
goodArray = file('dir_to_your_good_word_file).read().split()

# Then you use matching algorithm from difflib on good and bad word for every word in an array of words
import difflib

goodMachingCouter = 0;
badMacihngCouter = 0;


for iGood in range(0, len(goodArray)):
    for iWord in range(0, len(textArray)):
        goodMachingCounter += difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, goodArray[iGood], textArray[iWord]).ratio()
     
for iBad in range(0, len(badArray)):
    for iWord in range(0, len(textArray)):
        badMachingCounter += difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, badArray[ibad], textArray[iWgoodord]).ratio()

goodMachingCouter *= 100/(len(goodArray)*len(textArray))
badMacihngCouter *= 100/(len(badArray)*len(textArray))

print('Show the good measurment of the text in %: '+goodMachingCouter)
print('Show the bad measurment of the text in %: '+badMacihngCouter)
print('Show the hootnes of the text: ' + len(textArray)*goodMachingCounter)
```

The code will be slow but accurate :) I didn't run and test it please do it for me and post the correct code :) because I wanna test it too :)

Answer (score 1):

The following link contains a list of positive and negative polarised emotions on the scale of [-5, 5]. Just try to count up the scores based on the word matches and you can get the overall movie review score.

[AFINN](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=6010)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
vec =[]

for word in bag_of_negative_words:
    if word in mov_review1:
        vec.append(1)

for word in bag_of_positive_words:
    if word in moview_review1:
         vec.append(5)
```